# DynamicUpdateCommand stops working after QlikView restart

Tags: save, sql-update, ram, qlikview

I'm using `DynamicUpdateCommand` inside a macro in this way:

```
sub addOrder

  set choosen = ActiveDocument.Fields("NUMORD").GetPossibleValues

  for i = 0 to choosen.Count - 1
    set result = ActiveDocument.DynamicUpdateCommand("UPDATE * SET CHOOSE = 'S' WHERE NUMORD = '" & choosen.Item(i).text & "' " )

    if result = false then
      MsgBox result.ErrorMessage
    end if  
  next

end sub
```

Dinamic Data Update is enabled.

**It works, but, when I close QlikView and reopen it, it doesn't work anymore.** Even if try reloading.

I empirically realized that **to make it work again I need to click the "Save" button**, even without changing anything...

How can I solve this little issue? Maybe is it connected with RAM and way of saving .qvw file to the file system?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other solution I ended with this workaround, which saves the document programmatically on document opening:

- Document Properties... > Triggers > Document Event Triggers > OnOpen > Add Action(s)... > Add > External > Run macro > set Macro name = reactivateDynamicUpdateCommand
- Tools > Edit Module...: add this subroutine:

  ```
  sub reactivateDynamicUpdateCommand
     ' I know, it's weird
     '... but needed to reactivate DynamicUpdateCommand functionality after a restart
     ActiveDocument.Save
  end sub
  ```

It works, though a better solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 11 Dynamic Update can be done as Actions rather than through VB macro. It is preferable to use Actions when possible. However, sometimes even using Dynamic Update action I noticed freezes similar to what you described. I ended up adding one more dummy action right after Dynamic Update (e.g. assigning a value to dummy variable or adding **Selection -> Back** action to compensate triggering *OnSelect*).